# One thread one ByteBuffer NIO

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I am wondering about the best way to implement a multiuser NIO server with one thread and one buffer. Currently I use a selector to achieve this but I have only figured out how to do reading on all the clients. I am having trouble implementing write using the one buffer. Do I need a second buffer for writes? Or do I have to (unfortunately) have a write buffer per client? I wrote this example to easily show how I'm doing stuff, just so you know all processing happens within the scheduler's thread, I am not interacting with any state through another thread!

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
Selector selector = Selector.open();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);
Map<SelectionKey, SocketChannel> clients = new HashMap<>();

server.configureBlocking(false);
server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(43594));

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
        selector.selectNow();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = keys.next();
            keys.remove();
            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                    if (client == null)
                        break;
                    client.configureBlocking(false);
                    SelectionKey clientKey = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    clients.put(clientKey, client);
                }
            }
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                SocketChannel client = clients.get(key);
                if (client != null) {
                    buffer.clear();
                    client.read(buffer);
                    buffer.flip();
                    // do stuff with buffer
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, 600, 600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. For anything less trivial than an echo server, you need at least one buffer per channel, possibly two (read and write). Otherwise you can't possibly deal with partially read requests, or partially written responses.

You can associate the buffers with the channel via the `SelectionKey` attachment.

Comment: Are you sure of this? My current implementation works for many clients, although I haven't handled partial reads or writes. Are there any thorough examples you know on how to do this? I want to minimize garbage creation in my application.

Comment: Your current implementation 'works' *because* you haven't handled partial reads or writes. The moment you go to implement that, you will realize that you need a buffer or two per channel, to hold the pending data. Surely this is obvious? A buffer or channel doesn't impose any kinda Gc load, as it lasts as long as the connection, and in any case your primary concern must be correctness. You can get the wrong answer in zero time. It's of no relevance or interest.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it cleared things up. I want to pool my buffers to save on garbage, any suggestions there? Also I question the efficiency of attachments. I realize they can simplify my code and maybe(?) remove the need for my clients map by introducing a context. I am not doing real-time development although it is for a game that needs to run thousands of clients on a small amount of hardware. The system is based on messages being sent every 600ms if that helps!

Comment: On what grounds do you question the efficiency of attachments?